# how can i get the "qty" and "price" value and access in to the item [array] if i dont know the ids

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, ejs

[I am building a shopping cart and this is for the "previous orders" page in order to show the details. I am trying to print it in an (.ejs) file. The object consists of few nested object and inside one object other properties are referred by the mongoose product id while storing the purchase details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnY3x.png)

Comment: i have attached an image. but it got into the body  as a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the "items" object's keys and use that key to retrieve the whole item-object.

```
Object.keys(items).forEach(function(key,index) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(items[key])
})
```

Comment: it works after a good amount of tinkering with my objects."orders [element.cart.items[key].item.title]  " .  i ended up with this working code. as you can see the object nesting was complex.     thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `Object.keys(items)` to get a list of all the ids